# How to create d3 graph using data from Rails database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I learned to create d3 graph using the [d3 book](http://alignedleft.com/work/d3-book), in which all the dataset is included directly in the `<script>` tag, which is in turn included in the `html` body.

I now want to use d3 in my rails app, but I don't know how to:

1. Pass data from my Rails database to my d3 script
2. How to "partial out" the javascript? I have seen materials on "unobstrusive javascript", but they are usually about AJAX form submission and I have a hard time converting that to graph drawing (i.e. including a `<div>` with graph drawn using app data).

There is still not an answer that deals with both of these issues yet, so hopefully this becomes a reference for future Googlers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion requesting the data via AJAX would be the "cleanest" way to do that. You could use jQuery's ajax method to do a GET request to say '/get_data.json' ( which you have to add to your `routes.rb`), which would return you a JSON with the data.

Something like this.

```js
//your JS file
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '/get_data',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "{}", 
            success: function (received_data) {
               var div_where_to_draw = "div.mygraph";
               your_d3_function(div_where_to_draw, received_data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
            }
    });
function draw_histogram(where_to_draw, data_to_draw){
  //Your d3js code here
}
```

(Note that this JS code is a remake of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784164/what-is-the-best-way-to-update-d3-charts-using-ajax))

This is how your controller providing the data could look like(note I made a new controller, you might not want to do that and just use a new action in an existing controller):

```rb
#app/controllers/data_controller.rb
class DataController < ApplicationController
  def get_data
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {}
    end
  end
end
```

And this is how your data could look like:

```rb
#app/views/data/get_data.json
[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you also explain how I can include the graph in my view, ideally with the `.js` "partialed-out" to an external file? Do I need to create a `<div>` to contain the `svg`? Because my svg is being squished at the bottom...

Comment: You mean how to place your chart inside a div of your preference? I hardly ever used `d3js`, but I would assume that you can create a div somewhere with an `id` or a `class`, `<div id="d3-graph"></div>", and then in your JS file, you can append the graph inside that div. Check this example http://d3-generator.com/, paying attention to line 19 for example. Also have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860657/creating-a-basic-bar-chart-in-d3js. ( don't miss the jsfiddle link!)