# third party API data for ruby on rails web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, d3.js

I have a **ruby on rails** web application that uses third party API which provides some data that I want to visualize using **d3**. What would be the best way to gain access to the data? I've only practiced d3.js with static sets of data.

I read [How to create d3 graph using data from Rails database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494632/how-to-create-d3-graph-using-data-from-rails-database) and I read up on what AJAX is, but am still a bit lost. If AJAX is indeed ***the*** way, could anyone elaborate on the process?

Also when I'm doing this, is it best to use data that my web application has retrieved from the third party API, or should d3 directly fetch data from the third party API? Does it make a big difference?

Comment: For your last question: it really depends on the situation. If the data is something that your server needs to use, then the server should get it and send it to the view. If your server doesn't need it, then it would probably be easier to have d3 handle it. However, if a lot of people are going to use this application, then it would be best to periodically pull the data from the third party API and cache it on your server so that their API doesn't get bogged down.

Comment: thank you Jon, maybe I'm not correctly understanding what you mean by server. does server ever need to 'use' data other than hand them off to the application upon request?

Comment: The server _is_ your application, as opposed to the browser (where d3 runs) which is the client.

Comment: my bad, I thought you meant the database server. thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:**

To answer you question more directly, it would be better to get the results in Rails first, and then use them in your JavaScript, simply for the sake of keeping it better organized.

Also, making an AJAX call on page load to get the data versus using Rails is that (from experiences I've had), asynchronous calls would not be able to load the data before the JavaScript code tries to access it (if it takes too long). You would have to set the AJAX call to synchronous so that AJAX will return the data first, and then it will execute any following code. If it's a lot of data being returned, it could result in a really long page load, which is bad for the user experience.

---

You would probably need to use the RestClient gem.

In your **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'rest-client'
```

Then run `bundle install`.

Afterwards, create a model to use your API with:

```
rails g model ModelForMyApi
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`.

In your **ModelForMyApi** model:

```
class ModelForMyApi < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'rest_client'

    @url

    def self.getData
        response = RestClient(@url, { :content_type => :json, "Api-Key" => "put your API key here" }
    end

    def self.retrieve_results(myParameter)
         @url = "myApiUrl.com/stuff/?putYourParamNameHere=#{myParameter}"
        JSON.parse(ModelForMyApi.getData)
    end
end
```

So in your controller you can do something like:

```
class ExamplesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @results = ModelForMyApi.retrieve_results("superCoolParameter")
    end
end
```

And in your **index.html.erb** file to display the results:

```
<%= @results %>
```

That will display the entire JSON response. If you want to access the values from the key value pairs, take this example.

Pretend this is what your response looks like:

```
// This is a Rails JSON object, it has arrows.
// See below for how to incorporate this in your JavaScript
{
    "fruit" => "banana",
    "juice" => "orange juice"
}
```

Using

```
<%= @results['fruit']  %>
```

in your view would display "banana". And that's how I do my API calls with Rails. I don't know how to implement with d3.js, but I think the best approach would be to get the result first from the API, and then include those results in your JavaScript.

**Edit**

Since you need to use it with JavaScript, parsing the JSON response **in Rails** may not be the best approach. In this case, it may be better to do it exactly as I stated above, but removing the the `JSON.parse()` function from the `self.retrieve_results` method. This will return a normal JSON object instead of a Rails JSON object.

So in **ModelForMyApi**, remove the `JSON.parse` from the return line:

```
class ModelForMyApi < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'rest_client'

    @url

    def self.getData
        response = RestClient(@url, { :content_type => :json, "Api-Key" => "put your API key here" }
    end

    def self.retrieve_results(myParameter)
         @url = "myApiUrl.com/stuff/?putYourParamNameHere=#{myParameter}"
        ModelForMyApi.getData  #JSON.parse was removed 
    end
end
```

And in your JavaScript, all you have to do is this:

```
var jsonObj = #{@results};

// Output to log to see all the results you can play with
console.log(jsonObj);
```

Then, using the same JSON example from above (`{"fruit": "banana", "juice": "orange juice"}`), you can access the JSON in your JavaScript, like so:

```
jsonObj.fruit  // Will output "banana"
```

Now you can use your API results in your d3.js code.

---

The reason you need to remove the `JSON.parse` from the Rails method is because when you use it in your Rails method, it will make your response look like this:

```
//Javascript cannot interpret the arrows
{
    "fruit" => "banana",
    "juice" => "orange juice"
}
```

But you need it to look like this:

```
//JavaScript likes colons. No pun intended.
{
    "fruit": "banana",
    "juice": "orange juice"
}
```

Comment: so actually I got as far as retrieving and displaying JSON responses. I do that in ruby language, though, within my View file (.html.erb). If I wanted to use d3.js, is it possible to just put 
<%= javascript_tag do %>
d3 code
<% end %> in the body of my View file?

Comment: If you're using html.erb, just use normal <script> tags as you would in regular html. You set the variable like this: var jsonObj = #{@results}.

Comment: And yes, you can put it in the view file. It is best practice to put it at the bottom of the page just before the closing body tag (</body>).